# Celery using 100% CPU usage on AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery, cpu-usage

I have a web app running on an Linux 2/3.4.0 EC2 instance which is deploying slowly (eb deploy), and taking a long time for pages to load.

When I `eb ssh` into the instance, I run `top` and see two celery instances, each taking 45-60% of CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in /var/logs/ and ran `ls -alt` to get a list of the most recelty written to logs. This provided `celery_worker.stdout.log` and `celery_beat.stdout.log` at nearly the top of the list. When I `sudo vi celery_worker.stdout.log` and `celery_beat.stdout.log` I saw that the error `ImportError: The curl client requires the pycurl library.`

I was able to `cd /var/app` and enter my virtual env with `source venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate`.

When I tried to `pip install pycurl` I got dependency errors, and had to `sudo yum install libcurl-devel` and `sudo yum install -y openssl-devel`

Then I was able to `pip install pycurl`

Once pycurl was installed, the logs stopped being written to, and celery is no longer consuming CPU usage

TLDR:

1. ssh into your celery instance w/: `eb ssh`
2. run top w/: `top` to see what processes are sucking your CPU
3. find their logs
4. fix the problem